# Flutter get single variable from a list?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am getting data from firestore like this

```
              CollectionReference _collectionRef =
                  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Users');
              QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.get();

              // Get data from docs and convert map to List
              final allData =
                  querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();

              print(allData);
```

its printing data in list format like this

```
I/flutter (13500): [{number: +123131, shopname: ishaq shop, id: here i need doc id , lastupdate: , sendQty: }, {number: +1231231, shopname: ishaq shop, lastupdate: , id: gXVR4Sp3Cm3pii97Gh00, sendQty: }, {number: +123131, shopname: ishaq shop, lastupdate: , id: AM8KL6SxvFkCRQqpTjre, sendQty: }]
```

I just want to get a number from a list. I try something like

```
print(allData['number']);
print(allData.number);
```

but not working for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this. If it works you can iterate it through your list.
You convert your data to list here then try to call like a map. The reason why it is wrong. and replace final with list. It works fine

```
List allData =
              querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList()
```

Try

```
print(allData[0]['number']);
```

Comment: already try this showing Try correcting the operator to an existing operator, or defining a '[]' operator.

Comment: Also you need to replace final parameter on all data with list. I have edited now it works fine

Answer (score 0):

`allData` is a `List<Map<String, dynamic>>`, it means a list of maps (map: also called dictionary in java/swift and other language).
To Access a single variable you need the index of the dictionary first then use the key to access it.

```
var number = allData.first['number'];
print(number);
```

Right here I am printing the first item of the list, but you can access any item you want as long as you have its index.